# Edit multiple rows in MSSQL ".rpt" file

Tags: microsoft-excel, ms-sql, report

I have a report from MSSQL, that has been exported to an **.rpt** format. I have installed the necessary addons to open and edit the file in excel, however one such report has come out strangely.

For some reason, the file has exported to place all the columns into 1 column, rather than their individual columns. Eg:

```
| ExcelColA                   | ExcelColB |
+-----------------------------+-----------+
| SQLColA   SQLColB   SQLColC |           |
| etc...                      |           |
```

Is there any way I can edit this file to format it to properly populate the spreadsheet, without manually editing each row? (there are over 2000 rows in this one file alone).

Note - I am using the Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix.

When exporting this to a file, I think the problem was that the format didn't line up with anything that Excel recognised. So I went into MSSQL, then went to `Query > Query Options`, then chose `Results > Text > Output Format: "Comma Delimited"`

This exported to a recognisable format in excel.

Answer (score 0):

.rpt format is not a "report" in the usual sense. It is what you get when you tell SQL Management Studio to send query results to file.

Essentially, it is a fixed-width text file.

To open it in Excel, do the following:

1. Create a new sheet
2. On the ribbon menu, go to **Data**, then click **From Text**
3. A file-open dialog will open. Change the extension filter to show **All Files**, then select your .rpt
4. The **Text Import Wizard** opens. Select **fixed width**, click **Next**
5. Adjust the column breaks to the start of the column names (or underlines), click **Next**
6. Set the column formats, click **Finish**